# General solution to the homogeneous 2D Helmholtz Equation with Separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general analytic solution to the Helmholtz equation in 2D using separation of variables (only method I am currently familiar with). I've worked out the following

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + k^2 u = 0 
$$

Using separation of variables $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$

$$
Y\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2} + X \frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2} + k^2 XY = 0 
$$

Dividing by $XY$

$$
\frac{1}{X}\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2} + k^2  = 0 
$$

$$
\frac{1}{X}\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2} = -\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2} - k^2  = \lambda^2
$$

This can now separate into two equations since they both equal a constant

$$
\frac{1}{X}\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2} = \lambda^2
$$

$$
\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2}   = -(\lambda^2 + k^2)
$$

Solving for $X(x)$ gives $X(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$. However, I am not sure what to do with the $Y(y)$ term

Comment: Be careful. There should be two linearly independent solutions to each of these equations. You can only find specific solutions by adding boundary conditions